# What do the position and original_position fields mean in the github pull request comments API?

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

The github v3 API lets you [list comments on a pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#list-comments-on-a-pull-request) via

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/danvk/dygraphs/pulls/296/comments'
```

The response looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 11908831,
    "diff_hunk": "@@ -1521,16 +1576,6 @@ Dygraph.prototype.doZoomX_ = function(lowX, highX) {\n };\n \n /**\n- * Transition function to use in animations. Returns values between 0.0\n- * (totally old values) and 1.0 (totally new values) for each frame.\n- * @private\n- */\n-Dygraph.zoomAnimationFunction = function(frame, numFrames) {",
    "path": "dygraph.js",
    "position": 140,
    "original_position": 140,
    "commit_id": "bacf5ce283d6871ce1c090f29bf5411341622248",
    "original_commit_id": "335011fd4473f55aaaceb69726d15e0063373149",
    "user": { ... }
    "body": "I'm not sure why this is showing up in the diff -- did you move it?",
  }
]
```

(You can see this comment on github [here](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/296#discussion_r11908831).)

My question is: what exactly do the 140's in the "position" and "original_position" fields mean?

I'd like to translate this to/from line numbers on a particular commit. The [API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#review-comments) indicates that this is a line number in a unified diff, but I can't tell which unified diff it's indexing into. "dygraph.js" did not change from 335011f..bacf5ce, i.e. original_commit_id..commit_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in "[create comment](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#create-a-comment)"

```
position number Required.
```

> The line index in the diff to comment on.

If you expand the all diff associated with the [comment of PR296](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/296/files#r11908785), you will see that the 140th line of that diff is the one commented.
Go back to the last `@@` section and you will have the diff header matching that comment:

```
 -1521,16 +1576,6 @@ Dygraph.prototype.doZoomX_ = function(lowX, highX) {
```

If that PR evolved (changed its modification), `original_position` should refer to the previous line index before the last change.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make this a bit more explicit: for PR296, the base sha is 01275da4 and for that comment the "commit_id" is bacf5ce2. To get the correct line in the diff, I run "git diff 01275da4..bacf5ce2 dygraph.js" and delete the first four lines of header (which don't show up in the github UI). The comment then goes on line 141 of the diff (because github uses 0-based line numbers?).

Comment: I don't see any comment with this commit_id bacf5ce2. In fact, dygraph.js is not changed with this commit. What am I missing?

Comment: @MasudRahman You would see it at https://api.github.com/repos/danvk/dygraphs/pulls/296/comments

Comment: OK. Can you please help me understand how the position could be 140? I can see the comment--"I'm not sure why this is showing up in the diff -- did you move it?" between these two hunks--'@@ -1521,16 +1576,6 @@' and '@@ -1540,8 +1585,8 @@' of dygraph.js at  https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/296/files . I am spending days on this.

Comment: @MasudRahman position 140 is where the comment https://api.github.com/repos/danvk/dygraphs/pulls/comments/11908831 is associated. I don't have much info than what I already put in the answer above.